# Getting a "NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>" exception

Tags: django

**I tried very hard to find out the problem, but I failed.**
I am getting the following exception:

> Error-NoneType object has no attribute 'membership_type'

I think that the problem is in context as if I use context as None then the error occurs. 
I tried to use a foreign key to referring the Membership class and all the objects of it, but still get this error.

**models.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

import stripe

stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY

MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES = (
    ('Enterprise','ent'),
    ('Professional','pro'),
    ('Free','free')
)


class Membership(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    membership_type = 
models.CharField(choices=MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES,default='Free',max_length=30)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=15)
    stripe_plan_id = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.membership_type


class UserMembership(models.Model):
    user= models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stripe_customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    membership = models.ForeignKey(Membership, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

def post_save_usermembership_create(sender,instance, created, *args, 
**kwargs):
    if created:
        UserMembership.objects.get_or_create(user= instance)
    user_membership, created = UserMembership.objects.get_or_create(user= 
instance)

    if user_membership.stripe_customer_id is None or 
           user_membership.stripe_customer_id=='':
        new_customer_id = stripe.Customer.create(email= instance.email)
        user_membership.stripe_customer_id = new_customer_id['id']
        user_membership.save()


post_save.connect(post_save_usermembership_create,
                      sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)




class Subscription(models.Model):
    user_membership = models.ForeignKey(UserMembership, 
                      on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stripe_subscription_id = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_membership.user.username
```

**courses/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView,View

from .models import Course, Lesson

from membership_app.models import UserMembership
class CourseListView(ListView):
    model = Course

class CourseDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Course

class LessonDetailView(View):
    def get(self, request, course_slug, lesson_slug, *args, **kwargs):

        course_qs = Course.objects.filter(slug=course_slug)
        if course_qs.exists():
            course = course_qs.first()

        lesson_qs = course.lessons.filter(slug=lesson_slug)
        if lesson_qs.exists():
            lesson = lesson_qs.first()

        user_membership = UserMembership.objects.filter(user = request.user).first()
        user_membership_type = 
       getattr(user_membership.membership,'membership_type',None)
        # print(user_membership_type)

        course_allowed_membership_type = course.allowed_membership.all()

        context = {
           'object': None
        }

        if course_allowed_membership_type.filter(membership_type=user_membership_type).exists():
           context = {'object':lesson}

        return render(request, "courses/lesson_detail.html",context)
```

**templates**

```
 {% if object is not None %}
        {{ object.title }}
        {{ object.description }}
{% else %}
    <h3>Upgrade Membership</h3>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That's because `UserMembership.objects.filter(user = request.user).first()` did not find any matching record, and thus returns `None`.

Comment: Not quite, in that case the error would be `NoneType object has no attribute 'membership'` instead of `NoneType object has no attribute 'membership_type'`

Comment: i am facing still the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line.

```py
    user_membership_type = user_membership.membership.membership_type
```

The reason is that you are allowing `UserMembership.membership` to be a null value. So when you retrieve a `UserMembership` with `membership` equal to `None` and then try to get `membership_type` off of that it raises an error. I think that `getattr` is your best solution to this problem.

```py
    user_membership_type = getattr(user_membership.membership, 'membership_type', None)
```

Comment: still i have problem

Comment: no the error was same i recently edited my code that was suggested to me by you

Comment: There's a limit to how much help people on the internet can be. If your error hasn't changed at all (check the traceback's file name and line number) then my solution isn't the right one for this issue.